# How can I dump all svn data while I lost some revisions in the repository?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I want to dump my old svn source and load it to my new computer. My old svn repository is about 100GB huge.

- When I use `svnadmin dump /xx/Repositoryfile > mydump` to dump svn file, I got a 512Mb sized file. Finally, I found why:
- because the revision 302 has been lost. I can only get 1-301 revision's data.
- Even if use `svnadmin dump /xx/Repositoryfile -r 303:90000--incremental > mydump` to get the other source. It can't be loaded.

**How can I move all my svn data to the new location?**

Comment: i found i lost the following  files from the /repo_dir/db/revs/    301
636

Answer (score 4):

If you have a backup of the repository when it's not in corrupted state (i.e. when it has those lost revisions) then you can repair the repository. I suggest following these steps to repair the repository:

1. At first, you should check whether there are corrupted revisions other than 302 in the original dump. You can check the particular revision range for consistency by using the following command line:

   [`svnadmin verify /xx/Repositoryfile -r 302:HEAD`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html)
2. If there are no corrupted revisions except 302, then you should dump all
   revisions that are valid.

   [`svnadmin dump /xx/Repositoryfile -r 0:300 > dump1.dmp`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html)

   `svnadmin dump /xx/Repositoryfile -r 302:HEAD > dump2.dmp`
3. Locate the repository backup that has the 301 revision NOT corrupted and dump only this revision:

   `svnadmin dump /xx/Repositoryfile -r 301 > dump3.dmp`
4. Create a clean repository (via the command [`svnadmin create <repo-name>`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html)) and load all these dumps one by one ((!)*note that `dump3.dmp` must be loaded in second sequence*).

   `svnadmin load <repo-path> < dump1.dmp`

   `svnadmin load <repo-path> < dump3.dmp`

   `svnadmin load <repo-path> < dump2.dmp`

This way you will recover the repository. If you have other corrupted revisions other than 301, you will have to perform more steps but the approach is still the same. I do hope it helps!

Comment: My predecessor really give me a big mess.I have no backup can use. It seemd like the only way to slove it is check out then check in.Those mass data will take me a lot of time to move them.T O T